# Use other DataContract classes than the generated one's

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

Our customer sent us a WSDL file for their web service API. We used Visual Studio's "Add Service Reference" to consume it.

However: we only want to generate a service proxy, not the data contract classes. We want to reuse classes we already have within a referenced assembly.

- How to instruct "Add Service Reference" to not create Data Contract classes?
- ...or how to instruct WCF to use our Data Contract classes from the referenced assembly instead?

Comment: What about the "Reuse types" controls on the "Advanced" tab?

Comment: generate service contract + data contract and copy paste what you need and replace anything you need to use from the existing assembly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to the following options on the Advanced... part of "Add Service Reference":

[image]

which also map to the `/r` / `/reference` option in `svcutil.exe`.

This defaults to enabled, so if it isn't working: there's a good chance your types are not exact matches. The easiest way to ensure exact matches is to reference the same library dll from both projects, or *worst case* the same .cs file (a dll reference would be preferable, IMO). The data-contract namespace and name are the usual culprits here, and must match **exactly** (as must the members).

Answer (score 1):

Add your data contract classes (or even better create a new library for you data contract classes and reuse both in the service and client side) to the project including your service references. When adding a new service reference or updating an existing one, select "Reuse Types in Referenced Assemblies".

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I have one doubt about this.
I can access classes when adding service reference, this is ok
I can't see these classes when working with all projects inside the same solution in Visual Studio and adding "project" references.

Is there a way to test client side code using all projects inside the same solution in Visual Studio?

thanks